# shared jenkins library build.gradle error

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, groovy, shared-libraries

I am a newbie to groovy and gradle as i am building a small shared library for jenkins pipeline, when executing `gradle build` command i get an error `unable to resolve class hudson.model.Actionable`. I understand that gradle need this dependency to be able to execute this command. My noob question: how do i add the following libs to the dependencies block build.gradle?

- hudson.model.Actionable
- hudson.tasks.junit.CaseResult
- hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction
  i also have this error:
  Unable to resolve class NonCPS ,  unable to find class for annotation

**To sum it up, how do i add hudson.model and hudson.task and nonCPS class as dependencies in build.gradle?**

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to solve this, I am just putting this here in case anyone encounters the same issue:

```
compile 'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.24'
compile 'org.eclipse.hudson:hudson-core:3.2.1'
compileOnly 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
```